# Как и где установить комплекты для Qt?

Tags: c++, qtcreator

Скачивал Qt Creator через Offline-Установщик, по пути не было никаких компонентов. Хочу создать приложение для десктопа, но не хватает нужного компонента и я не знаю как найти его, особенно сегодня в России. **Название нужного компонента - Desktop (x86-windows-msvc2022-pe-64bit)**
Помогите, пожалуйста...

Искал на официальном сайте Qt, решения на ютубе, но нигде даже намека на решение

Comment: Скачал свежий инсталлятор Qt - там нет MSVC2022, только MSVC2019. Вы пробовали его устанавливать? На форумах Qt пишут, что последний msvc и с этой версией Qt прекрасно дружит (ну или наоборот :)).

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, ссылку на тот инсталлятор, который вы имеете в виду?

Comment: https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer-oss